# RelativeLayout onDraw

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, ondraw

I create a subclass of RelativeLayout，the use of it in the layout file.In the layout file also defines some components widget.Overwrite the OnDraw painted a picture，The picture can not draw on the top, but the control block.
Like this:

[image]

How do I get the picture to the layout of the above.the picture is and move according to the finger movement..thanks.